# SAS: How to create a table that lists the variable names of another table

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am starting out with SAS and PROC SQL, and I want to do a very simple task as described below but am having trouble.

```
data test;
input x_ray y_chromosome z_sword;
cards;
1 2 3
4 5 6
4 7 8
7 8 9
7 9 10
7 10 11
;
```

In the table *test* we have three variables, *x_ray*, *y_chromosome*, and *z_sword*.

My goal is to make another table, let's say, *result*, that looks like this.

```
data result;
input name $;
cards;
x_ray
y_chromosome
z_sword
;
```

I looked up ways to do this online, but all the methods are very well beyond my understanding and I simply do not believe that such a simple process has to be so complicated.

May I have some help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PROC CONTENTS.

```
proc contents data=test noprint out=result;
run;
```

If you only want the variable names and not the other information you can use dataset option to limit the variables kept in the RESULT dataset.

```
proc contents data=test noprint out=result(keep=name) ;
run;
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for!!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any shorter and simpler answer than @Tom, just another two ways for reference.
Use dictionary table:

```
proc sql;
  create table result as select name from sashelp.vcolumn where libname='WORK' and memname='TEST';
quit;
```

or query them by I/O functions:

```
data result;
  rc = open('work.test');
  if rc then do;
    do i = 1 to attrn(rc,'nvars');
      name = varname(rc,i);
      output;
    end;
  rc = close(rc);
  end;
run;
```

Comment: If you are looking for short/cryptic methods try:  `proc transpose data=test(obs=0) out=result; var _all_; run;`